# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key"

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, migrate

Ive got the error:
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key")
when i try to migrate my laravel db .Heres my schema...

```
    Schema::create('estoques', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id_loja')->unsigned();
        $table->increments('id_produto')->unsigned();

        $table->integer('quantidade');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });

    Schema::table('estoques', function($table) {
        $table->foreign('id_loja')->references('id')->on('lojas');
        $table->foreign('id_produto')->references('id')->on('products');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation: `Auto-incrementing UNSIGNED INTEGER (primary key) equivalent column.` Therefore as it's setting it as the primary key you can only have one column marked with `$table->increments`.

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations)